# Integral of the reciprocal of quartic expression

Tags: integration

I've tried to solve $\int \frac{dx}{ax^4 + b}$ using substitution method but made the problem more complicated. 
Could anyone pls give another idea? 
Thanks.

Comment: Mathematica gives the following disaster: $$\frac{-\log \left(-\sqrt{2} \sqrt[4]{a} \sqrt[4]{b} x+\sqrt{a}
   x^2+\sqrt{b}\right)+\log \left(\sqrt{2} \sqrt[4]{a} \sqrt[4]{b} x+\sqrt{a}
   x^2+\sqrt{b}\right)-2 \tan ^{-1}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2} \sqrt[4]{a}
   x}{\sqrt[4]{b}}\right)+2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2} \sqrt[4]{a}
   x}{\sqrt[4]{b}}+1\right)}{4 \sqrt{2} \sqrt[4]{a} b^{3/4}}$$

Comment: Are not there conditions on $a$ and $b$? E:g., for $a>0$ and $b<0$, this integral is easily manageable.

Comment: Hint: you can factor the denominator as $$ax^{4}+b=(\sqrt{a}x^{2}+\sqrt{2}a^{1/4}b^{1/4}x+\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}x^{2}-\sqrt{2}a^{1/4}b^{1/4}x+\sqrt{b}).$$

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume $a>0$ and $b<0$ ($a<0$ and $b>0$ is similar). One has
$$
\int\frac{dx}{ax^4+b}=\frac{1}{a}\int\frac{dx}{x^4-\frac{|b|}{a}}.
$$
Then,
$$
\frac{1}{x^4-\frac{|b|}{a}}=\frac{1}{\left(x^2+\sqrt{\frac{|b|}{a}}\right)\left(x^2-\sqrt{\frac{|b|}{a}}\right)}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{a}{|b|}}\left(\frac{1}{x^2-\sqrt{\frac{|b|}{a}}}-\frac{1}{x^2+\sqrt{\frac{|b|}{a}}}\right).
$$
These terms can be straightforwardly integrated.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int \frac{1}{ax^4+b} dx=\frac{1}{a} \int \frac{dx}{x^4+c^2}, ~~c^2=b/a.$$
$$I=\frac{1}{a}\int \frac{(1/x^2)dx}{x^2+c^2/x^2}=\frac{1}{2ac} \int \frac{(1+c/x^2) dx - (1-c/x^2)dx}{x^2+c^2/x^2}$$
$$I=\frac{1}{2ac} \left(\int\frac{(1+1/x^2) dx}{(x-c/x)^2+2c}- \int\frac{(1-1/x^2) dx}{(x+c/x)^2-2c}\right)$$
Now let $x-c/x=u, x+c/x=v$, then
$$I=\frac{1}{2ac} \left(\int \frac{du}{u^2+2c}- \int \frac{dv}{v^2-2c} \right)$$
$$I=\frac{1}{a(2c)^{3/2}}\left(\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{2c}}
+ \frac{1}{2} \ln \left(\frac{x-\sqrt{2c}}{x+\sqrt{2c}}\right) \right), c^2=\frac{b}{a}.$$